# Duplicate Records when using Joins in SQL - Image data

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates

Im having an issue where a query with a simple join is returning duplicate records. Heres the code that i have:

```
SELECT DR.DOCUMENTNAME, DR.REVISIONNUMBER, BD.DOCUMENTDATA
FROM DOCUMENTREVISION DR LEFT JOIN
     BINARYDOCUMENT BD
     ON DR.DOCUMENTARCHIVENUMBER = BD.DOCUMENTSUBGROUP
WHERE BD.DOCUMENTSUBGROUP = '160200001'`
```

This returns:

[image: View Results Here]

As a note, im unable to use distinct since DocumentData column is an image data type. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc...) that you are using.

Comment: Im on SSMS- 17 environment

Comment: What data is in the archiveNumber and DocumentSubGroup? Those are the columns you join on, but are not displayed in the question.

Comment: How do you think we can help if you don't give table structure???

Comment: So basicaly these two tables hold document information for projects. Archive number and documentsubgroup are simply job numbers that im joining on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from other solution but just slight modification with `TOP` clause :

```
SELECT DR.DOCUMENTNAME, DR.REVISIONNUMBER,
       (SELECT TOP (1) BD.DOCUMENTDATA
        FROM  BINARYDOCUMENT BD
        WHERE DR.DOCUMENTARCHIVENUMBER = BD.DOCUMENTSUBGROUP
       ) as DOCUMENTDATA
FROM DOCUMENTREVISION DR 
WHERE DR.DOCUMENTARCHIVENUMBER = '160200001';
```

You can also simplify the same with `APPLY` :

```
SELECT DR.DOCUMENTNAME, DR.REVISIONNUMBER, BD.DOCUMENTDATA
FROM DOCUMENTREVISION DR OUTER APPLY
     ( SELECT TOP (1) BD.DOCUMENTDATA
       FROM  BINARYDOCUMENT BD
       WHERE DR.DOCUMENTARCHIVENUMBER = BD.DOCUMENTSUBGROUP
     ) BD;
WHERE DR.DOCUMENTARCHIVENUMBER = '160200001';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `LEFT JOIN` is unnecessary because it is being undone by the `WHERE`.

I am guessing that the duplicates are coming from the `JOIN`.  If so, uou can do what you want using a subquery.  I think something like this will work:

```
SELECT DR.DOCUMENTNAME, DR.REVISIONNUMBER,
       (SELECT BD.DOCUMENTDATA
        FROM  BINARYDOCUMENT BD
        WHERE DR.DOCUMENTARCHIVENUMBER = BD.DOCUMENTSUBGROUP
        FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
       ) as DOCUMENTDATA
FROM DOCUMENTREVISION DR 
WHERE DR.DOCUMENTARCHIVENUMBER = '160200001';
```

This returns only one match from `BINARYDOCUMENT`.

Note:  `FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY` is ANSI-standard syntax, supported by many databases but not all.  Some use `LIMIT` and some use `SELECT TOP`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Im getting syntax error on the Fetch Statement            
"Invalid usage of the option FIRST in the FETCH statement."                          
When i hover over the FETCH it says expecting ')', EXCEPT OR UNION

Comment: @UsmanAhmed . . . As mentioned in the answer, use the appropriate logic for your database (which was not tagged when I answered).  And, for the record, SQL Server has supported `FETCH` for many years.